# Typed racket error with check-random

Tags: unit-testing, scheme, racket

I'm trying to convert a project over to typed racket from racket and I'm encountering errors with working code because of the testing engine.

I've reduced it to the smallest piece of code I can create that reproduces the problem:

```
#lang typed/racket

; provides check-expect and others for testing
(require typed/test-engine/racket-tests)

(: bar (-> Positive-Integer Integer))

(check-random (bar 6) (random 6))

(define (bar x)
  (random x))

(test)
```

And the errors are:

```
. Type Checker: type mismatch
  expected: Pseudo-Random-Generator
  given: Any in: (check-random (bar 6) (random 6))

. Type Checker: type mismatch
  expected: Positive-Integer
  given: Any in: (check-random (bar 6) (random 6))

. Type Checker: Summary: 3 errors encountered in:
  (check-random (bar 6) (random 6))
  (check-random (bar 6) (random 6))
  (check-random (bar 6) (random 6))
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this? I really want to be able to use the type checking features if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, I can help, but it depends a lot on what exactly you want, and where you're going with this.

Short overview: there are multiple testing frameworks for Racket. You're using the one that's built for the teaching languages. It has several nice features, but generally speaking rackunit is the testing framework used by others.

It appears to me that the typed version of the teaching-language-test-framework doesn't include support for check-random. I'll check on this on the mailing list. That would steer you toward rackunit.

Unfortunately, rackunit doesn't include the "check-random" form. Fortunately, it's not hard to implement. Here's my implementation, attached to your code.

```
#lang typed/racket

; provides check-expect and others for testing
(require typed/rackunit)

;; create a new prng, set the seed to the given number, run the thunk.
(: run-with-seed (All (T) ((-> T) Positive-Integer -> T)))
(define (run-with-seed thunk seed)
  (parameterize ([current-pseudo-random-generator
                  (make-pseudo-random-generator)])
    (random-seed seed)
    (thunk)))

;; run a check-equal where both sides get the same PRNG seed
(define-syntax check-random-equal?
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ a b) (let ([seed (add1 (random (sub1 (expt 2 31))))])
               (check-equal? (run-with-seed (λ () a) seed)
                             (run-with-seed (λ () b) seed)))]))

(: bar (-> Positive-Integer Integer))
(define (bar x)
  (random x))

(check-random-equal? (bar 6)
                     (random 6))
```

I should probably tell you about several important differences between the two testing frameworks.

- You don't need to call "(test)" at the end; the tests run interleaved with the rest of the code.
- Since the tests are interleaved with the code, they must appear below all of the definitions required to run the test.
- Nothing is printed when a test succeeds.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The documentation stated that I needed to call (test) because I am not using one of the teaching languages and when I tried it without (test) the tests were not run. I guess rackunit does not require the (test) procedure call. I will test this tonight. I am typing on my iPhone. Sorry for the formatting. Your procedure looks like it will meet my need. Thank you.

Comment: It works beautifully except now I can't make include work to include the other file. I guess I'm going to have to keep the tests in my main source file.

Comment: I notice that you write `include`... are you being instructed to use `include` as part of an assignment? If not, you probably want to be using something like `require`, instead....

Comment: Not an assignment - I left school a long time ago. I was trying to see what would work. I realize now that `require` is better because, if my memory serves, it will only pull it once while `include` will just drop the file right there every time the `include` procedure is called.

Comment: More generally, `require` is a mechanism that respects hygiene (cf. Macro Hygiene), and allows programmers to specify visibility at the module level. A module, essentially, is a separately compiled unit of code. But yes, `require` > `include`.

Comment: You might also be interested in using `module+` to group your tests. So, for instance, you can write (module+ test ... tests go here ...). In this way, your test code can access all of the functions defined in the enclosing module, but the tests don't get run when, e.g., someone `require`s the outer module.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on `module+`. I am still learning my way around Racket as a development environment and I'm finding all sorts of great features. I'm using it do be able to develop applications that can be compiled for OS X, Windows, or Linux all with the same source code.